# How to add myAppHelp.pdf file in netbeans platform application's menubar?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, embedded-resource, menubar

I made Desktop App in netbeans platform in Java Swing. Now, how can i put myapp's helpOfApp.pdf  file in netbeans platform app(MyApp)'s menu bar?

Comment: 1st I would recommend converting `help.pdf` to `help.html` where the HTML is simple 3.2 variety. ..

Comment: @AndrewThompson i convert help.pdf to help.html. after that, how to add this .html file to menubar in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to add this .html file to menubar in my app?

- Add a menu item to a menu that is added to the bar.
- Add an `Action` (or `ActionListener`) to the menu item.
- Add an accelerator of <kbd>F-1</kbd> (help).
- On action.

  - Get an URL instance using something like
     `URL urlToResource = this.getClass().getResource("/path/to/the.resource");`
  - Open a `JEditorPane` (non-editable, and possibly with a link listener)  pointing to `urlToResource`.

See the relevant 'keyword+java+tutorial' for more details on each step.

---

Tip: ensure all resources (e.g. linked HTML, CSS, images etc.) are:

- accessed by relative path
- on the run-time class-path of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to above code

```
URL urlToResource = this.getClass().getResource("/path/to/the.resource");
jEditorPane1.getPage(urtToRecource);
```

Might Work